# Odoo reporting - display 0 when values is null

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am designing reports for Odoo in OpenOffice reports designer. 
I need to show rate per unit and discount in column as below

```
"₹. 95.0 each 
 5% Discount"
```

I am able to display these fields on report. 
Issue is when discount is 0, it displays blank in report as below

```
"₹. 95.0 each 
 % Discount"
```

I want to show 0 instead if blank. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When field value is `null` it will display an empty string.so use condition to display `'0'`:

```
[[ o.discount or '0' ]]
```

To display for example `5%` or `0`, use:

```
[[ o.discount and  formatLang(o.discount) + '%' or '0']]
```

Comment: @Thakur feel free to accept this answer if you think this is the solution.

Comment: it is useful but i require output as 5% or 0, how can i append percent symbol to discount field?